# Como listar a quantidade de registros abertos e quais foram atendidos na mesma sql?

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Preciso obter a quantidade de chamados abertos e a quantidade de chamados abertos que foram atendidos, isso tudo agrupado por mês.

Estou tentando assim:

```
select T_aberto.mes, T_aberto.qtd_aberto, T_atendido.qtd_atendido FROM

                (select TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM') as mes, count(incidente_id) as qtd_aberto from incidente

                where incidente_id > 0 
                and data_registro > '01/06/2019'

                group by TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM')
                order by TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM')

                ) T_aberto,

                (select TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM') as mes, count(incidente_id) as qtd_atendido from incidente

                where incidente_id > 0 
                and incidente.inc_status in ('c', 'p')
                and data_registro > '01/06/2019'

                group by TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM')
                order by TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'YYYY/MM')

                ) T_atendido
```

Mas o resultado não é exibido como preciso, pois gera algumas linhas a mais, e fora de ordem.

Vejam:

```
MES      QTD_ABERTO    QTD_ATENDIDO
2019/06   908            902
2019/06   908            968
2019/06   908            899
2019/07   977            902
2019/07   977            968
2019/07   977            899
2019/08   965            902
2019/08   965            968
2019/08   965            899
```

Alguma sugestão de como resolver isso? Grato!

Comment: Adicionar `where  T_aberto.mes = T_atendido` não resolveria?

Comment: Disponibilize a estrutura de suas tabelas, alguns dados de exemplo e o resultado que espera desses dados. Assim podemos testar solução e sugerir as melhores

Comment: Prezados, agradeço a atenção. Consegui resolver a questão usando um CASE.

   
 select TO_CHAR(date_logged, 'YYYY/MM') data, count(incident_id) incident_id,
   count(case when inc_status in ('c', 'p') then incident_id end ) as atendido
 
 from incident
   
    INNER JOIN jptsys_tabledata d on d.table_name = 'incident'
       
    where incident_id > 0 
    and date_logged > '01/06/2019'
   
    group by TO_CHAR(date_logged, 'YYYY/MM') 
    order by TO_CHAR(date_logged, 'YYYY/MM')

Comment: Publique como solução